# Random Number Generator In Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

Hey so I'm relatively new to coding and have started making a discord bot, mainly just for having fun on my discord server. If you are familiar with the Animal Crossing series you will be familiar with the "Stalk Market", I wanted to make a command that gives somebody a random number after they do the command "+turnipprice". Whenever I tried doing the command it would stop at "Current Turnip Price Is..." heres the code I was trying to do it with.

```
    const m = await message.channel.send("Fetching Turnip Prices...");
    m.edit("Current Turnip Price Is...");
    m.edit(math.random());
  }
```

**solved**

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you wrote `math.random()`, JS is case sensitive, and that means `math.random()` and `Math.random()` are 2 different expressions, specifically, JS will complain that `math is not defined` when calling `math.random()`.

So you should change your code to use `Math.random()`:

```
const m = await message.channel.send("Fetching Turnip Prices...");
    m.edit("Current Turnip Price Is...");
    m.edit(Math.random());
  }
```

You can see a live difference between output for `math` and `Math` `.random()`, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x56g1pye/)

Also, please note that in your question you did not specify exactly what the problem was, and it almost seems like the question was cut abruptly, please make sure you post complete and understandable questions so that members of SO can help you

Comment: Do you think theres a way to make it say "Bells!" after the random number and in the same message? @Mor Paz

Comment: Yes, use the back tick syntax for string formatting, for example: `m.edit(\`${Math.random()} Bells!\`);`. Also, if this answer helped you please be sure to mark is as the answer for future members who encounter it.